# Use Galaxy S3 as universal bluetooth audio receiver

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, bluetooth, audio, bluetooth-audio

I have an old GS3 and would like to use it as a receiver to connect other bluetooth devices such as iPhones, laptops, and other Android phones to my home stereo via the 3.5 mm jack.  Does anyone know if there's an app that will allow this? If there's no way to do it via bluetooth, it may also be acceptable to use WiFi as the transmission medium.

Answer (score 0):

I found an app that works over WiFi using AirPlay--it's called AirBubble.  Still would like to know if there's a way to do this using bluetooth though.